# Snowflake is not respecting Retry-After response header on 502 and 429 status code

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

While working with snowflake external functions we found a issue, and we believe Snowflake is not respecting Retry-After response header.

The external function invokes the AWS lambda function via AWS API gateway which in-turn invokes a 3rd party API (does some data enrichment), and return the response back to the snowflake client with status 200 (for happy case scenario)

For a batch request of 50, if we try to process a 1 million records, then after certain time, our 3rd party API starts sending HTTP 429 and we send the same to the snowflake client, **along with Retry-After header in response of 10 seconds**. (As the third party API tends to get overloaded with requests after a certain time). This is an indicator which tells Snowflake to scale back the rate at which it sends rows, and retries sending batches of rows that were not processed successfully.

To our surprise Snowflake is not actually respecting the parameter and retrying the request again within 1-3 seconds. Please find attached the cloud watch logs for the lambda function:

[image]

How can we slow down the request rate, so snowflake starts invoking after 10 seconds thereby giving some time for the 3rd party API to recover from 429?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @Roddy It's clearly written in the explanation and refer the image as well, although we are passing 10 seconds but snowflake is still sending within 1 seconds which is wrong

Comment: Yes, I "clearly" see you added an actual question to your post about 4 minutes after I asked.

Comment: The first line was pretty explicit "While working with snowflake external functions we found a issue, and we believe Snowflake is not respecting Retry-After response header." I added deliberately the statement later at the end as I found someone was not able to understand

Comment: Because there literally was no question until you added the last statement. It read like a bug report. Now it is clear what you're trying to do and what your question is. Remember a good percentage of people here are not native (or necessarily fluent) English speakers: it is better to be precise.

Comment: Thank you do have any actual response or the answer for the question asked, anyways thanks for the suggestion, much appreciated